# How to check if an interval is negative?

Tags: plsql

```
declare
  v_interval interval day(0) to second(0);
begin
  select t.duration
  into v_interval
  from my_table t;

  dbms_output.put_line(case when v_interval < 0 then 'negative' else 'not negative' end);
end;
```

If the value of the interval selected is `+0 00:25:00`, it is still evaluated to be less than 0. Why? Also, how to properly check if it is negative?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing an interval against a number; you should use a zero interval instead:

```
case when v_interval < INTERVAL '0 0:00:00.000' DAY(0) TO SECOND(0) then 'negative
```

for example, this

```
select case
        when INTERVAL '0 0:25:00.000' DAY(0) TO SECOND(0) > INTERVAL '0 0:00:00.000' DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)
          then 'positive'
          else 'negative'
       end
from dual
```

gives `'positive'`